# cucumber protractor is not running with multiple tags

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am having few scenarios tagged with @test and @high. When I run with a single tag with below syntax it works fine.

package.json

```
"smoke": "babel-node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractorConf.js --presets-env --cucumberOpts.tags \"@smoke\"",
```

But when i run this, to run scenarios tagged with both @test and @high, nothing happens and 0 scenarios are invoked.

package.json

```
"high": "babel-node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractorConf.js --presets-env --cucumberOpts.tags \"@test,@high\""
```

I tried with many options like below, but nothing works.

```
--cucumberOpts.tags "@test" --cucumberOpts.tags "@high"
--cucumberOpts.tags @test --cucumberOpts.tags @high
--cucumberOpts.tags "(@test and @high)"
--cucumberOpts.tags "@test and @high"
```

please help me on how to run multiple AND and OR scenarios. below is my package versions.

```
"cucumber": "^4.2.1",
"protractor": "^5.3.2",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^5.0.0"
```

Below is the actual output, when I invoke the commands.

```
c:\Personal\ATDD  (protractortest@1.0.0)
λ npm run high

> protractortest@1.0.0 high c:\Personal\ATDD
> babel-node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractorConf.js --presets-env --cucumberOpts.tags "@test,@high"

(node:8100) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[11:48:21] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:48:21] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
(node:8100) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.


0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
Cucumber HTML report c:\Personal\ATDD\reports\html/cucumber_reporter.html generated successfully.
[11:48:25] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:48:25] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

To explain what happened, you were expecting both of the tags specified to be run, even if the scenarios didn't have both tags.

For that, you need the `or` keyword in the tag expressions.

`"@test or @high"` is what you were looking for.

**More info on tag expressions**

To run a single tag:

- `--cucumberOpts.tags "@tag1"` - Run Scenarios tagged with @tag1
- `--cucumberOpts.tags "not @tag1"` - Run Scenarios not tagged with @tag1

If you want to run multiple tags, or specify tags not to run:

- `--cucumberOpts.tags "@tag1 or @tag2"` - Run Scenarios tagged with `@tag1` or `@tag2` or both
- `--cucumberOpts.tags "@tag1 and @tag2"` - Run Scenarios tagged with both `@tag1` and `@tag2`
- `--cucumberOpts.tags "@tag1 not @tag2"` - Run Scenarios tagged with `@tag1` that aren't tagged with @tag2

For more complex Tag Expressions you can use parenthesis for clarity, or to change operator precedence:

- `--cucumberOpts.tags "@tag1 and not (@tag2 or @tag3)"` - Run Scenarios tagged with tag1, where you do not have tags @tag2 or @tag3
- `--cucumberOpts.tags "(not @tag1) and (@tag2 or @tag3)"` - Run Scenarios not tagged with `@tag1` but are tagged with `@tag2` or `@tag3` or both

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue here. Actually, I misunderstood that @test and @high will invoke the scenarios tagged with either any one. I now know that it will invoke a scenario which has tagged with both @test & @high like below

```
@smoke @test @high
Scenario: ...
Given ... 
When ...
Then ...
```

and not like

```
@smoke @test
Scenario: ...
Given ... 
When ...
Then ...

@smoke @high
Scenario: ...
Given ... 
When ...
Then ...
```